# jQuery load, can see the div in the source code but it is not being displayed

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery's load function to load an error message if an ajax request fails into a div. I can see the div with the loaded contents in my source code but it's not showing up on the page. Any idea what's going on?

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {

    var element = $(this);

    var id = element.attr('id');

    var note = $('#note-' + id).val();

    $('#message').show();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/index.php/notes/new_note",
            data: "id=" + id + "& note=" + note,
            success: function() {
                $('#notes-' + id).load('/index.php/ads #notes-' + id)
                $('#note-' + id).val('')
            }
        });
        $('#message').load('/index.php/ads #message')
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Which div is not loading, notes or message?  Also, please show the html.

Comment: Well if you look at it with Firebug you should be able to tell what's going on. Probably some CSS is hiding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably put the message load into the error handler for the AJAX call or, perhaps, retrieve it from the data returned by the AJAX call, rather than executing it after the AJAX call is made.  This is because the AJAX call is asynchronous and it is likely that you are loading the message before the AJAX call is complete.  What you do is entirely dependent on your server side code.  I'd explore the option of letting the server-side simply generate the entire container, error and all, then simply replacing the contents with the returned value from the call instead of re-invoking some AJAX to get the updated HTML after the original call is complete.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "/index.php/notes/new_note", 
    data: "id=" + id + "& note=" + note, 
    success: function(html) { 
                 $('#note-container').html(html);
             } 
});
```

Comment: How might I go about doing this? I've looked at the jQuery documentation for error handeling but can't quite figure out how to implement it. As a side note I'm using CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1):

Has `#message` got any opacity applied to it (either applied through CSS, or by using the fadeTo/ fadeOut jQuery methods). Does the same go for all its parents? Does it have it's `visibility` CSS property set to 'hidden'?

`show()` only changes the `display` css property of the element. It won't change the `opacity`, `visiblity` or any of the like of the element, or its parents.

Comment: I was assuming that "source code" meant server-side.  My suspicion is that there simply isn't anything in the "#message" div when the load is invoked because the first AJAX call hasn't finished yet.